# Depending on numeric value and text, coloring table background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a money goal table. What I want is, every time I complete a goal for example 100 dollars,

if I write in total $100.00, "A/A 1" automatically changes to green.

If I write, $200.00, "A/A 1 and 2" to turn green.

Is it possible to be affected by HTML text? Thanks a lot!!!

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  top:0; 
}

th {
  background:purple;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:4px;
}

td {
  background: #376282;
  color: #fff;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:4px;
  text-align:center;
}

#money {
  background: gold;
  color: blue;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:4px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table id="table-id">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A/A</th>
      <th>MONEY</th>
      <th>GOAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>&#x2713;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>$200</td>
      <td>--</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>$500</td>
      <td>--</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<h3>Total: 
<span id="money">€100,00</span></h3>
```

Comment: Note: ids should be unique - ie. there should be only _one_ of any id on the page.

Comment: You can't do it in HTML alone. You'll need some dynamic code that will run on the webpage to color the relevant elements. Javascript is most commonly used for this. Is JS an option? If yes, what have you tried?

Comment: You're also dealing with two different _types_ of currency here: Euros and Dollars. and it's unclear if that's relevant. Should the `#money` total be in dollars too? How are you going to handle amounts after the decimal point? Should they be ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key steps might be:

1. Select up all the `tbody` rows, and iterate over them.
2. A function to take the number string content of an element, and coerce it to a proper number.
3. Some new classes that can be added to the relevant table cells: one "green" which can be applied to the row, and "tick" which can render a tick as content.

I've made a couple of concessions/assumptions in this example

1. All amounts are using decimal *points*. There's some confusion in your question about which locales you're using (leading to a mix of Dollars and Euros) which isn't particularly useful.
2. I've removed the currency symbols from the amounts to make the parsing of the numbers easier. You can change the "MONEY" table heading to "$" to ensure meaning isn't lost.
3. I've left the last column empty.
4. I've removed the background color from the `td` CSS rule and added it as the `tbody tr` rule instead to ensure the new applied green colour sticks.

```js
// Function to get the number from the text content of
// a DOM element
function getNumber(el) {
  return parseFloat(el.textContent);
}

// Cache the rows. Cache the formatted total by passing
// the #money element through the getNumber function
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
const total = getNumber(document.querySelector('#money'));

// For each row get its second and third cells. From the
// second produce a formatted number from its text content.
// If it's less than the total add a "green" class to the row,
// and a tick to the third cell
rows.forEach(row => {
  const sum = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)');
  const tick = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)');
  if (getNumber(sum) <= total) {
    row.classList.add('green');
    tick.classList.add('tick');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 75%;
  top: 0;
}

th {
  background-color: purple;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 4px;
}

tbody tr {
  background-color: #376282;
}

td {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

#money {
  background-color: gold;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

.green { background-color: green; }
.tick:after { content: '✓'; }
```

```html
<table id="table-id">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A/A</th>
      <th>$</th>
      <th>GOAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>200.25</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<h3>Total $<span id="money">200.25</span></h3>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)
- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: That's really awesome!!!! Thank you so much.. Out of curiosity.. Is there any way to add this symbol $ before 100, 200.25 etc.. ?

Comment: Ok I found it , I just add this to css td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "$"; }

Answer (score 0):

Form your question I get the point that if you enter value 100 or above 100 then the first column (A/A) should turn green (background color). This can be achieve through adding js.

```js
 Goal();
 
 
   function Goal() {
      var table = document.getElementById("table-id");
      var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

      var totalMoney = 0;

      for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var moneyCell = row.cells[1];
        var goalCell = row.cells[2];

        var money = parseFloat(moneyCell.textContent.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, ""));

        if (money >= 100) {
          row.cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
          goalCell.textContent = "✓";
        } else {
          row.cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
          goalCell.textContent = "--";
        }

        totalMoney += money;
      }

      document.getElementById("money").textContent =
        "€" + totalMoney.toFixed(2);
    }
```

```css
 .table {
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
    }

    th {
      background: purple;
      color: #f1f1f1;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 4px;
    }

    td {
      background: #376282;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 4px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #money {
      background: gold;
      color: blue;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 4px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
 <table id="table-id">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A/A</th>
        <th>MONEY</th>
        <th>GOAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>&#x2713;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$510</td>
        <td>--</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>$15</td>
        <td>--</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h3>Total: <span id="money">€100,00</span></h3>
```

Comment: that's great. But only the first row turns green. (Because of row.cells[0] I guess). How do all 3 horizontal rows turn green? Thanks